# Copy from textarea to anther textarea but the value of the second textarea should not change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two textareas. I am copying data from one to another but if I change data in the first textarea then data in the second textarea is also changed which is obvious.

My requirement is like this: Suppose I have written "country" and it has been pasted to the second textarea. Now if I replace "country" with "anyother" then in the second textarea "country" should not be replaced. If I write something in the first textarea which is new(not replacement) then only that data will be pasted.

Is it possible to do?

My code till now:

```js
function showRelated(e) { 
  //$('src2').html($('src1').html()); 
  $('#src2').val( $('#src1').val() ); 
}
```

```html
<textarea name="source" id="src1" cols="150" rows="20" onkeyup="showRelated(event)"></textarea> 
<textarea name="source2" id="src2" cols="150" rows="20"></textarea>
```

the second text area is hidden from user.whatever the user writes will be copied to second textarea and will be transliterate.The requirement is like this if the user replace some data then also it should not effect the data which he already entered.that is why i need to maintain a copy without using database.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Or you just want us to whip up some code for you?

Comment: Imagining your scenario is very difficult. Please post some code for quicker help and to avoid downvotes

Comment: Please provide the code you currently have so that we can assist you better.

Comment: You are copying content manually or programatically?

Comment: yes. Provide the Javascript/jquery code you currently have.

Comment: provide the code inside: Untitled-4.js

Comment: You need to paste the actual code (not the script include tag) into your question.

Comment: My code tilll now                                            <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="trans.js"></SCRIPT>    <textarea name="source" id="src1" cols="150" rows="20"  onkeyup="showRelated(event)"></textarea>                      <textarea name="source2" id="src2" cols="150" rows="20"></textarea>                               my trans.js                                                                       function showRelated(e) {
//$('src2').html($('src1').html());
$('#src2').val( $('#src1').val() ); }

Comment: post your code on the very top. Click on edit on your initial question and paste it there. You need to be specific and post your code clearly so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#one').on('blur', function() {
    $('#two').val($('#two').val() + '\n' + $('#one').val());
});
```

Comment: i can not use button.

Comment: @MithunDebnath Any reason why not? You'll need some sort of trigger. When do you want the copy to actually occur?

Comment: the second text area is hidden from user.whatever the user writes will be copied to second textarea and will be transliterate.The requirement is like this if the user replace some data then also it should not effect the data which he already entered.that is why i need to maintain a copy without using database.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect what you just said. You're wanting to append to what's already there.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't the easiest to decipher, but perhaps you want to store translated text into a second textarea?

```
<textarea id="one"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>

var translate = function(input) {
    // TODO: actual translation
    return 'translated "' + input + '"';
}

var $one = $("#one");
var $two = $("#two");

$one.on('blur', function() {
    $two.val(translate($one.val()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok it seems this is what you want:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="src1"></textarea>
<textarea id="src2"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$("#src1").keyup(function() {
     var src1_val = $(this).val();
     var src2_val = $("#src2").val();
     var new_string = src2_val + src1_val;
     $("#src2").val(new_string);
});
```

Comment: Using keyup will keep adding characters which is not the desired result. You need a single event, like `blur()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some thing like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/1pfbhepf/)

```
$("#one").blur(function() { // triggering event
     var one = $(this).val(); // place values in variable to make them easier to work with
     var two = $("#two").val();
     var three = one + two;
     $("#two").val(three); // set the new value when the event occurs
});
```

Comment: This is similar to what I put, but one slight modification to this is `var three = two + one;` since it seems a bit more natural for newer additions to be appended at the end.